# What is "Comp Type" in surfaceflinger logs?

Tags: android, android-source, surfaceflinger

I am working on an issue and for that I had to look into dumpsys of SurfaceFlinger. There I am seeing there are two composition types, DEVICE and CLIENT. What is the difference between these two and what they actually mean? I couldn't find any documentation online that explained it.

Want to understand difference between DEVICE and CLIENT comp type in surface flinger.